# jupyter notebook doesnt show other drive of files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i want to access the files from D drive but jupyter notebook doesnt show D drive of files

could you please give the ways to access D drive on jupyter notebook?

Comment: https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/intro-to-earth-data-science/open-reproducible-science/jupyter-python/get-started-with-jupyter-notebook-for-python/
There's a section called `Navigate Files Using the Jupyter Notebook Dashboard`